# ARM64 Android emulator throws OutOfMemery even though vmHeapSize set high

Tags: android

On my old Intel Mac, I run Android Studio, in which I have a x86-64 flavour of Andoid Emulator running. I have its 'hm.ramSize' set to 3072MB, and its 'vm.heapSize' to 576MB.
When I run an app which tries to allocate a 400MB large local variable on the heap, everything works.

On my new Apple M1-based Mac, I have just installed the very same version of Android Studio, and I have created a ARM64 flavour of the very same Android Emulator, also configured with the same values for 'hm.ramSize' and 'vm.heapSize'.

When I run the very same app there, the app crashes with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 406425616 byte allocation with 3408168 free bytes and 44MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 6816336, growth limit 50331648
```

AFAIK the only difference is the x86-64 vs. ARM64 thing. On ARM64 the 'vm.HeapSize' doesn't seem to take. ('growth limit 50331648??')

Would anyone have some tips?